# Is there anything I can do to create a search box function for a page (and several pages linked to it) on SharePoint (modern view)?

Tags: python, search, sharepoint

I'm creating a "data catalog" on SharePoint that consists of a page of links to other pages. Objects are clickable and take the user to a page where related Attributes are listed. (I know that I'd be better off using data cataloging software, but it's a non-starter atm.)

I know that SharePoint has a "search box" web part, but it's apparently available for classic view only, and we are using modern view (and can't change to classic.) I really need a search box web part. Is this possible? I'm python-literate so if I could code something using python or something comparable, I probably could.

Anybody else solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SharePoint Framework modern search Web Parts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners) in modern page.

[Get to know about SharePoint Framework(SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)